# как вытащить файл из input, jquery и передать его через ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Есть input, как при клике на div вытащить выбранный пользователем файл в переменную и потом передать его с помощью ajax на сервер.

```js
$('#download_on_server').click(function(){
  console.log($('#new_clide').files);
});
```

```html
<form class="slider_control_conteyner">
  <h5>Добавить новый слайд:</h5>
  <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" id="new_clide">
  <div id="download_on_server">Загрузить</div>
</form>
```

дело в том что при использовании "files" когда файл выбран всё равно выводит "undefined"

Comment: Попробуйте так `$('#new_clide')[0].files`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй такой вариант.

```
$('#download_on_server').click(function(){

    // вот так получаешь данные по файлу
    var fileData = $('#new_clide').prop('files')[0]; 

    // получаешь объект FormData. его будем передавать по Ajax
    var formData = new FormData();

    /* добавляем полученные данные о файлу в FormData, первый аргумент('newSlide') 
    это ключ ассоциативного массива, по которому мы на бэке получим данные по файлу.
    То есть если на бэке php то $_FILES['newSlide'] */
    formData.append('newSlide', fileData);

    //отправка по ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url куда шлём',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            //
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: не помогло, я создал отдельную тему по этому вопросу  с более подробным описанием https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896856/Передача-файлов-с-поомщью-ajax

Comment: глянул код. У тебя файла нет в formdata. замени var image = $('#new_clide')[0].files. На var image = $('#new_clide').prop('files')[0]; Как я писал в коде выше.

Comment: ну тут прикол в том что по ajax в твоём примере передавался не файл, а массив. То есть данные то по файлу передавались всё равно, но попадали в массив пост, просто php не мог понять что пришёл именно файл.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $("#cmdSubmit").bind("click", function () {
       file = $("#fileInput")[0].files[0];
        alert(file);
        file = $("#fileInput").prop('files')[0];
        alert(file);
        
    });        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="file" id="fileInput" />
         <input type="submit" value="submit form" id="cmdSubmit">        
    </form>
```