# Передача файлов с поомщью AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

Всем привет, помогите разобраться с отправкой файла с помощью AJAX, суть моей проблемы состоит в том что у меня есть

```html
<form class="slider_control_conteyner" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h5>Добавить новый слайд:</h5>
  <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg,image/png" id="new_clide">
  <div id="download_on_server">Загрузить</div>
</form>
```

При нажатии на div с надписью "Загрузить" 
Запускается jquery обработчик

```js
var image = $('#new_clide')[0].files;
```

Он записывает фотку в объект, проверяет формат файла, чтобы удовлетворял требования, смотрит на размер файла, и в случает не верных значений этих параметров, соответственно выводит ошибку.

далее, если все проверки прошли успешно,

```js
const formdata = new FormData();

formdata.append('newSlide', image);

console.log(formdata.getAll('newSlide'));
```

создаётся новый элемент объекта FormData и в него заносится картинка, вроде бы заносится, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом выполняется ajax запрос кидающий эту картинку серверу

```js
$.ajax({
 url: '../modules/new_slide.php',
 data: formdata,
 contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
 type: 'POST',
 cache: false,
 success: new_slide

});
```

Вот после этого уже и возникает проблема, на сервере я пытаюсь прочитать массив $_FILES, а он почему то пустой

Однако если я пытаюсь прочитать $_POST, то в нём уже что то есть, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, что я делаю не так, и как корректно нужно передать было картинку, чтобы я смог её нормально добавить на сервер!?

Comment: `var image = $('#new_clide')[0].files[0];` И еще, если нет на то необходимости, то можно добавить в `FormData` сразу все значения полей формы. У вас бы это выглядело так: `const formdata =  new FormData($(this).closest('form')[0]);`